# Refactor Django FormView Context

Tags: python, django, sendmail, formview

I currently email myself submitted form information as an admin so I can contact a customer. I could not figure out how to simply pass all of the form variables to the Django Email Template. I instead had to define the individually. Is there a way to pass all of the context variables so I don't have define each and every one of them?

```
form_class = CustomProjectBuildRequestForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
success_message = "Form successfully submitted!"

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()

    context = {
        'first_name': form.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
        'last_name': form.cleaned_data.get('last_name'),
        'email': form.cleaned_data.get('email'),
        'phone': form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number'),
        'zip_code': form.cleaned_data.get('zip_code'),
        'project_title': form.cleaned_data.get('project_name'),
        'project_description': form.cleaned_data.get('project_description'),
        'contact_method': form.cleaned_data.get('preferred_contact_method'),
    }

    template = get_template('request-custom-project/email_template.html')
    content = template.render(context)

    send_mail(
        'New Custom Project Request',
        html_message=content,
        message=content,
        from_email=context['email'],
        recipient_list=['test@gmail.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )

    return super(PMPIndex, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2):

`from.cleaned_data` should be a [simple dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) (or a variant like `OrderDict`). The [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) expects a `dict`-like object as context. Hence you could simply use `cleaned_data` as `context`: `content = template.render(form.cleaned_data)`.

If you need some additional values in the template, I suggest the following

```
   context = {
       'some': 'extra',
       'values': 1,
   }
   context.update(form.cleaned_data)
   content = template.render(context)
```